# Is is possible to somehow override default PowerPoint's File -> Print window (VSTO addin)?

Tags: c#, vsto, ms-office, powerpoint, office-interop

Specifically, what I'm talking about, whenever a user selects File, then Print, PowerPoint's default print window is shown. Can I 'override' it to have *Custom Selection* preselected and some range of slides already put in (like slides 1,3,5)?

Answer (score 0):

The [Introduction to the Office 2010 Backstage View for Developers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/ee691833(v=office.14)) article states the following:

> Can I repurpose one of the existing definitive command buttons, fast command buttons, or tabs by changing its onAction callback attribute? For example can I change the file Save button so that is has an additional type, or displays only one file type?

It is not possible to override these commands from the custom UI XML markup or by using the object model. Using the DocumentBeforeSave event is one alternative, but using that doesn't really change the functionality of the individual commands that show up in the Change File Type gallery in the Backstage. A better solution would be to consider hiding the built-in UI and rebuilding it fully with custom commands.

So, you can hide the built-in Print button from the backstage UI and add your own with custom functionality. The [PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.presentation.printout) method of the `Presentation` class prints the specified presentation with the specified range.